# C++ passing a value by reference that is created in the function call (inline)

Tags: c++, reference

I want to understand why C++20 complains when I try do the following, perhaps someone can help.

I have a method defined, like so:

```
void doStuff(Point& dest) {
    ...
}
```

When I try to do the following:

```
doStuff(Point(x,y));
```

I get the error: `C++ initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

This goes away when I make `Point& dest` -> `const Point& dest` or if I define a new variable for the `Point(x,y)` however in the case that I do not want to defined dest as a const or I dont need a variable, why is it that the compiler complains about this? There are cases where I want to pass it in as a reference and others where I want to keep it inline with the function call to keep things more straight forward. Obviously the example I gave here is really simple, but you get the idea.

Of note I know that I can cast it like so:

```
doStuff(static_cast<Point&>(Point()));
```

But this seems really unnecessary, I'd like to find a way to achieve this without all the other nonsense. Any help is most appreciated! I might be missing something really obvious, I am no C++ expert.

Comment: This rule was added to the language as a protection measure. If `doStuff` modifies `dest`, then it is likely a mistake to give it a temporary which is together with the modifications lost after the call. If the function does not modify the parameter it should take by `const` reference. If it takes ownership of the object it should take a rvalue reference. Of course this doesn't always apply in which case you can overload on rvalue reference, but are you sure that passing a `Point` temporary to `doStuff` makes logical sense here if `doStuff` modifies it?

Comment: Great explanation, thanks so much a lot for taking the time.

Comment: In my case yes it would be appropriate to pass the object like so. I want to maintain the ability to pass in a reference via an lvalue if needed, however it isnt always required, since the object is a "context" for an execution chain and should be discarded after.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to turn this compiler check off?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Older versions of MSVC used a C++ dialect in which this rule was not applied. But even if you could change this, it would be a really bad idea. Your code will become non-portable and very confusing to every C++ programmer. It is also very common for overload resolution to depend on this rule to make the correct choice in terms of program logic.

Comment: *"I do not want to defined dest as a const"* -- this is one place where details matter: do not **want** to define `dest` as `const` or not **able** to do so (because the function modifies `dest`). If it's just "want" then decide if you want that more than you want to be able to pass in a temporary. If it's "able", then the rationale for why the language does not permit this applies (explained in the proposed duplicate).

Comment: Right it was implied that I can't since modifications will be made along the chain

Comment: C++ nonsense never ceases to amaze me haha. I know a lot of people probably think this is a really good compiler check, but the fact that this check is forcing me to add a whole new method definition to account for both scenarios is actually beyond me. It should be implied that the if its passed in as an rvalue that it's expected the result is specific only to that method chain. However in other cases I may want to maintain it past that method chain. Really silly in my opinion. But hey, maybe I'm not seeing the whole picture just yet.

Comment: @BenDol Nonsense? What nonsense? This is not a "compiler check" to turn on or off. Binding a temporary value to a reference to non-const is prohibited by the standard. When C++ programmers see a `const something&` parameter, they know: this is an _input_ parameter. When we see `something&` (without `const`), we assume: this is an _output_ parameter.

Comment: @BenDol *"it was implied that I can't since modifications will be made along the chain"* -- no, this was not implied. Partly because you wrote "do not want" instead of "cannot" burt mostly because the question has no mention of modifications that will be made along the chain. (Maybe that was lost in a pre-publish revision?) I've re-read the question and see nothing that would be inconsistent with someone whose reason for not marking `dest` as `const` is a personal dislike of the keyword `const`. That's not to say that's your reason, only that there is certainly no implication to the contrary.

Comment: @heap underrun how can I turn it off? So far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accept (overload with) rvalue references `void doStuff(Point&& dest)`

---

side note: you can pass it directly to lvalue reference version if that's what you want.

```
void doStuff(Point& dest);
inline void doStuff(Point&& dest) { doStuff(dest); }
```

Comment: Most swift and accurate answer I've had in a long time! `You can accept an answer in 11 minutes` Thanks so much

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to turn this compiler check off?

Comment: @BenDol I think there is no. temporary cannot bind to non-const lvalue reference is a universal c++ rule (not limited to parameter). All you need is add the rvalue overload as I mentioned. plus it's then pretty clear to others that you intentionally treat rvalue as lvalue and not by accident.